# How can I change the size of the markers inside the legend?

Tags: plotting, legending

I'm trying to plot multiple plots in just one. I need to have small markers inside the plot, but in the legend it would be more convenient to have bigger markers.

I'm trying to change `LegendMarkerSize`, but it only changes the shape of the whole legend (without changing the size of the points). Here's an example of my struggle:

I have:

```
ListPlot[{Prime[Range[25]], Sqrt[Range[40]]}, 
 PlotMarkers -> {Automatic, 3}, 
 PlotLegends -> 
  PointLegend[{"Primes", "Roots"}, LegendMarkerSize -> 3, 
   LegendFunction -> None, LegendLabel -> "Legend"]]
```

[image]

And changing only `LegendMarkerSize` from `3` to (say) `23`, I get:

```
ListPlot[{Prime[Range[25]], Sqrt[Range[40]]}, 
PlotMarkers -> {Automatic, 3}, 
PlotLegends -> 
 PointLegend[{"Primes", "Roots"}, LegendMarkerSize -> 23, 
 LegendFunction -> None, LegendLabel -> "Legend"]]
```

[image]

As you can see, only the text have shifted. How can I increase the size of the markers inside the legend without modifying the size of the markers in the plot on itself?

Thank you very much.

Answer (score 10):

**Update:** To have the legend markers match the markers in plot, you can add the option `LegendMarkers -> ChartElementData["SimpleMarkers"][[All,1]]` in `SwatchLegend`:

```
ListPlot[{Prime[Range[25]], Sqrt[Range[40]],Log@Range[40]}, 
 PlotMarkers -> {Automatic, 9}, 
 PlotLegends -> SwatchLegend[{"Primes", "Roots", "Logs"}, LegendMarkerSize -> 15, 
   LegendMarkers -> ChartElementData["SimpleMarkers"][[All,1]], 
   LegendLabel -> Style["Legend", 20]]]
```

[image]

**Original answer:**

You can use `SwatchLegend` with options `LegendMarkers -> "Bubble"` and `LegendMarkerSize -> 15`:

```
ListPlot[{Prime[Range[25]], Sqrt[Range[40]]}, 
 PlotMarkers -> {Automatic, 3}, 
 PlotLegends ->  SwatchLegend[{"Primes", "Roots"}, LegendMarkerSize -> 15, 
   LegendMarkers -> "Bubble",  LegendLabel -> Style["Legend", 20]]]
```

[image]

Answer (score 4):

I fiddled around a bit. `LegendMarkerSize` is really counterintuitive. Apparently, it does only control the size of the `Graphics` containing the markers, not the markers themselfes. How is this?

```
ListPlot[{Prime[Range[25]], Sqrt[Range[40]]},
 PlotMarkers -> {Automatic, 3},
 PlotLegends -> PointLegend[
   {"Primes", "Roots"},
   LegendMarkerSize -> 15,
   LegendMarkers -> {{"\[FilledCircle]", 15}},
   LegendLabel -> Style["Legend", FontSize -> 20]
   ]
 ]
```

[image]

Comment: Has this changed? See: `PointLegend[{Red, Red, Green, Blue, Black}, Range[10]
 , LegendMarkerSize -> 90, 
 LegendMarkers -> {Charting\`CommonDump\`GraphicsPlotMarkers[][[1]], 
   Charting\`CommonDump\`GraphicsOpenPlotMarkers[][[1]], 
   Charting\`CommonDump\`GraphicsPlotMarkers[][[3]], 
   Charting\`CommonDump\`GraphicsPlotMarkers[][[1]]}
 ]` or does it depend on where the option gets used?

Comment: Hm. I don't understand what you mean.

Comment: Oops. I guess my comment didn't make as much sense as I thought. I meant that in my example the `LegendMarkerSize` does determine the size of the actual markers in the legend and not the Graphics containing the whole legend. It is not a matter of the Mathematica version though as I ran your code and there it does not change them. It seems to depend on the type of `LegendMarkers` that you use.

Comment: For a simpler example just replace your LegendMarkers above with `LegendMarkers -> {Charting\`CommonDump\`GraphicsPlotMarkers[][[1]]}`

Comment: Okay, the bullets in the legend get larger. What is the problem?

Comment: Not a problem but different from your example and different from your text: "Apperently, it does only control the size of the Graphics containing the markers, not the markers themselfes.".